# how to execute ubuntu (scrot) command in php(codeigniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I want to take screen shot of web page by using php in ubuntu. so I want to run "scrot" command from php function.I had used imagegrabscreen(); its not working in ubuntu but its working in windows.

> shell_exec('scrot ~/Pictures/my_desktop.png');
>
> exec('scrot ~/Pictures/my_desktop.png');

please give solution.

Comment: you should refer this article

http://tecadmin.net/create-screenshots-of-websites-html-with-php-script/

Comment: Thanks Abbas , you really gone help me.I just modified your code slightly.And its work correctly.

When installing wkhtmltoimage-i386,

 # cd /tmp
 # wget http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltoimage-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2
 # tar xvjf ./wkhtmltoimage-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2
 # chown **apache:apache** ./wkhtmltoimage-i386
 # chmod +x ./wkhtmltoimage-i386
 # mv ./wkhtmltoimage-i386 ./usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage-i386
 # cd ~

instead of **apache:apache** i used my system credential. e.g username= root and password =  (blank)